# Is there a tool I can use to test out multiple vpn tunnels in one machine?

Tags: vpn, curl, wget, tap, tun

I use `wget -q -O  https://checkmyip.com/csv` to determine if I am connected to a VPN but I want to verify multiple VPN tunnels on the same machine. Is there a tool that can allow me to send a command that will allow me to load a csv/json file from the remote server based on the tunnel I use? I think curl has an interface option - would that be one?